# How to detect when the focus is out of a Div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onblur

I'am working on a dynamic form that generates a number of Divs. I would like to detect if the focus was lost from the entire div not just from one input.

[image]

As the picture shows , I have multiple identical forms , the issue here is how to detect if the user is done editing one of the forms?

The forms are created dynamically using an ng-repeat.

```
<fieldset  data-ng-repeat="response in responces" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index" >
    <div id="customFrom">
    <input type="text" ng-model="response.code" name="" placeholder="Code">
    <input type="text" ng-model="response.rank" name="" placeholder="{{ 'app.forms.responses.rank' | translate }}" >
    <input type="text" ng-model="response.value" name="" placeholder="{{ 'app.forms.responses.value' | translate }}">
    <input type="text" ng-model="response.name" name="" placeholder="{{ 'app.forms.createQuiz.fields.name' | translate }}" class="labelTextQuestionCreation">
    <button class="remove"  ng-click="removeResponse($index)" ng-show="deteteResponceOption">-</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

What is the best way to add an action when the users jumps from one form to another? I need to detect when a form (Div) lost the focus in order to execute a function. 
Thank You.

Comment: angular api has core directives for most events . Might also consider disabling other form while each is dirty and not saved

Comment: ngMouseleave wont be useful in this case, also I need multiple forms because the user can add as many entries as he wants and after each modification of a form I need to send its data to the server that's why I want to detect the lose focus event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed The Problem By using a hidden input that indicates the index of the form, the value of this input is add to the model, because, I'am using a ng-repeat so each row has its own scope. In addition, I used the ng-focus directive to check if an input has focus, and when it does, I call a function that I called `getSelectedElement(index), the function verifies if the index has changed or not, and if we are in a new index we update/Insert the row in the data base. Here is my code for the solution :

**HTML**

```
 <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="response in responces track by $index" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index">
    <div ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"  >
    <input type="text" ng-model="response.code" name="" placeholder="Code"  ng-focus="getSelectedElement(sectionIndex)">
     <input type="text" ng-model="response.index"  ng-init="response.index=sectionIndex"   ng-value="sectionIndex"  ng-focus="getSelectedElement(sectionIndex)" ng-show="false">
    <input type="text" ng-model="response.rank" name="" placeholder="{{ 'app.forms.responses.rank' | translate }}"  ng-focus="getSelectedElement(sectionIndex)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="response.value" name="" placeholder="{{ 'app.forms.responses.value' | translate }}" ng-focus="getSelectedElement(sectionIndex)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="response.name" name="" placeholder="{{ 'app.forms.createQuiz.fields.name' | translate }}" class="labelTextQuestionCreation" ng-focus="getSelectedElement(sectionIndex)" >
    <button class="remove"  ng-click="removeResponse($index)" ng-show="deteteResponceOption">-</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.getSelectedElement=function(index){
 var oldIndex=$scope.responcesSelectedIndex;//Variable to watch, it gets updated when we gain focus. initially it has -1 as a value, and we gain focus on a field it gets updated
 if(oldIndex==-1){//-1 indicates that we are in the first element, no previous index, no need to do any thing just update the old index.
     oldIndex=index;
 }
 $scope.responcesSelectedIndex=index;//Update the old index to be the current so when we call the function again we will have two index values, the new one (As a parameter) and the old one ($scope.responcesSelectedIndex)
 var newIndex=$scope.responcesSelectedIndex;
     if(oldIndex!=newIndex){//Jumping to the new Form
        console.log("Update or Create");
        //Do What You want Here

    }
```

}

It is not a perfect solution, but it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your problem, the best solution is to use [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

Each element with ng-model will need the following attribute:

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

Then will look like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="response.code" name="" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" placeholder="Code">
```

With the ng-model-options, the model is only updated when the focus is lost on the form field. You can then have a $watch statement, which is only triggered when the model is updated.

In the $watch callback, when a change to any attributes of the main array if detected, you can run the models through validation to know if all the data is filled out and proceed with the execution of the desired function.

```
$scope.$watch('responces', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // onBlur triggered an update to an attribute of **responces**
    // run your input validation here
}, true);
```

Comment: Thank You Artem this works for the input fields, but the issue here to check if we moved to the next form or not, because if we moved to the next form I need to store the previous one in the data base in order to reduce the waiting time for the queries. We are not sure that the user will edit all the existing forms so when he edits one we call the WS and update the database.

Comment: By a single form, I assume you mean a horizontal row of fields. I understand your dilemma. The complexity of the solution depends on how many rows you expect to have. With a reasonable amount of data, I have previously simply sent all the data via an API and the back-end updated all entries, when a change is detected. Approached the concept as a "set" instead of "update".